# Illegal string offset on row_fix.php on line 34/39

Tags: php, wordpress

**Hello everyone, I have a huge problem, I am creating a website in wordpress but in some parts of the site displays this error message:**

Warning: Illegal string offset 'css' in C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ wordpress \ wp-content \ themes \ realty_v1.7 \ realty_v1.7 \ includes \ vc_extend \ row_fix.php on line 34

Warning: Illegal string offset 'css' in C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ wordpress \ wp-content \ themes \ realty_v1.7 \ realty_v1.7 \ includes \ vc_extend \ row_fix.php on line 39

This is the .php file:

```
    <?php
function carell_build_style($bg_image = '', $bg_color = '', $bg_image_repeat = '', $font_color = '', $padding = '', $margin_bottom = ''){
    $has_image = false;
    $style = '';
    if((int)$bg_image > 0 && ($image_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $bg_image, 'large' )) !== false) {
        $has_image = true;
        $style .= "background-image: url(".$image_url.");";
    }
    if(!empty($bg_color)) {
        $style .= vc_get_css_color('background-color', $bg_color);
    }
    if(!empty($bg_image_repeat) && $has_image) {
        if($bg_image_repeat === 'cover') {
            $style .= "background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size: cover;";
        } elseif($bg_image_repeat === 'contain') {
            $style .= "background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size: contain;";
        } elseif($bg_image_repeat === 'no-repeat') {
            $style .= 'background-repeat: no-repeat;';
        }
    }
    if( !empty($font_color) ) {
        $style .= vc_get_css_color('color', $font_color); // 'color: '.$font_color.';';
    }
    if( $padding != '' ) {
        $style .= 'padding: '.(preg_match('/(px|em|\%|pt|cm)$/', $padding) ? $padding : $padding.'px').';';
    }
    if( $margin_bottom != '' ) {
        $style .= 'margin-bottom: '.(preg_match('/(px|em|\%|pt|cm)$/', $margin_bottom) ? $margin_bottom : $margin_bottom.'px').';';
    }
    return empty($style) ? $style : ' style="'.$style.'"';
}

function row( $atts, $content ) {
    $class = explode( "{", $atts['css'] );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'js_composer_front' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wpb_composer_front_js' );
    wp_enqueue_style('js_composer_custom_css');
    $style = carell_build_style($bg_image, $bg_color, $bg_image_repeat, $font_color, $padding, $margin_bottom);
    return '<style>'.$atts['css'].'</style><section class="'.str_replace( ".", "", $class[0]).'"><div class="container"><div class="row">'.wpb_js_remove_wpautop($content).'</div></div></section>';
}
add_shortcode( 'vc_row', 'row' );
?>
```

**I do not know what to do. help me!**

Comment: try this `function row( $atts, $content = null )`

Answer (score 0):

Please check function row(),

```
function row( $atts, $content )
```

In this function You are passing $atts which might not be an array with index 'css'

Comment: I'm honest, I'm really ignorant in this field, I'm rehearsing for my friend, this afternoon I should show him a draft. How can I move in practice to solve the problem? Thank you so much for your reply!

Comment: Please  check where this function row() called, and check what value are passed? It should be array and having index 'css'